# how can I dequeue a styles and scripts of all plugins in WordPress except my plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created this code but it's not working i don't know why anyone can help or correct it for me? thanks

```
function dequeue_plugins_styles_scripts() {
    // Dequeue all styles except for my-specific-plugin
    $plugins = get_plugins();
    foreach ($plugins as $plugin_path => $plugin) {
        if ($plugin['TextDomain'] !== 'my-specific-plugin') {
            wp_dequeue_style($plugin_path);
        }
        var_dump($plugin_path);
    }
    
    // Dequeue all scripts except for my-specific-plugin plugin
    $all_scripts = wp_scripts()->registered;
    foreach ($all_scripts as $script_handle => $script) {
        $src = $script->src;
        if (strpos($src, '/plugins/') !== false && strpos($src, 'my-specific-plugin') === false) {
            wp_dequeue_script($script_handle);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_plugins_styles_scripts', 9999);
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_plugins_styles_scripts', 999 );
```

I have tried this code to dequeue a styles and scripts of all  plugins except my plugin and default WordPress assets so I don't let other plugins to overlap in my admin plugin dashboard

Comment: Instead of looking at plugins via `get_plugins()`, you just want to look at all queued CSS and JS which you can get from the globals `$wp_styles` and `$wp_scripts;`. Just iterate over the items in the `queue`, perform your logic, and then call `wp_dequeue_style` and `wp_dequeue_script` on the handle.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thanks for answer. I would like to do that but the problem is it's also removing the default styles and scripts of WordPress and i want to keep it, i only want to dequeue the plugins in my plugin dashboard

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? How exactly is your plugin affected by what the other plugins might have added?

Comment: @CBroe Some Plugins have scripts that are forced to overlap on my Plugins pages, which makes using my plugin not easy and causes some problems in the style. I just want to isolate the plugins only in my plugin pages.

Comment: Then you would first of all have to find a way to make this apply only to your own plugin's pages, no? Otherwise those additional scripts & stylesheets will be missing on _their_ respective admin pages.

Comment: So what about this is not working? `wp_dequeue_style($plugin_path)` probably does not make much sense, I suppose - you will have to handle the stylesheets the same way, as you are already trying to handle the scripts - get all of them, and then compare their path with the plugin base path.

Comment: @wordpressfixxer, I was showing you how to get the handles, which is required for the dequeue, just do it for the problematic ones, and only in your area.

Comment: @CBroe about find a way to make this apply only to my own plugin's pages, I'm already have a way to do that

Comment: @CBroe i did the stylesheet like script way as you said, and it's worked, thank you so much